# Computer not booting up after reconnecting to electricity

Tags: boot, power

Recently I started having problems with a bit older PC (quadcore with 4gigs of ram). When I disconnect it from electricity for few minutes/hours for example when I want to clean it from dust or move it to some another place in my house I am unable to start it up again.

I set everything up and when I press power up button nothing happens. After trying for few minutes in starts up and boot up like if everything is all right. What I am most nervous about is that I think that it is getting worse and each time it takes a bit longer to "fix" itself.

The problem exists only on the first boot up after reconnecting it to the electricity. I was not being able to find anything wrong when I shut down my computer and start it up again later on (after this first boot up).

What could be the cause of this? And more importantly how can I fix it?

---

EDIT:

I don't really want to disconnect it when I don't absolutely have to since I am afraid that it would not start up again. Anyway it looks like in few days I would have to disconnect it so I can try to swap the battery then but I don't think it would help.

The date and time settings are correct and I did not notice any problem with BIOS settings as well. I am not that tech savy but I have altered device boot order some time ago and it is still as I left it. Guess it looks like to be a problem with power supply.

To answer the other comments. Motherboard is MB GIGABYTE P43-ES3G and about power supply I am not really sure. It's 400 or 500W, can't remember the brand. I would have to look it up somewhere.
Anyway I have another 500W or 550W power supply which I bought for one of my older PC and ended up using for only a week before I bought brand new computer. Maybe I could try that? Even thou I was not being used it's quite old and don't have sata connectors.

Everything is connected including graphic card. When I press power button nothing happens. Disks don't start to spin, no sound. Nothing at all like if it is not connected to the electricity. **However I've noticed one thing that I forgot to write before. Lights on keyboard (capslock and so on) was very slightly blinking.**

I've installed CPUID HWMonitor and this is my results. However I have no idea how to detect if it is out of ordinary.

```
WHAT            MIN         MAX         CURRENT
-----------------------------------------------

Voltages
CPU VCORE       1.056V      1.248V      1.056V
DDR             1.904V      1.888V      1.904V
+3.3V           3.344V      3.360V      3.360V
+5V             4.865V      4.892V      4.892V
+12V            12.416V     12.480V     12.480V
VBAT            3.264V      3.264V      3.264V

Temperatures
SYSTEM          30°C        30°C        30°C
CPU             29°C        39°C        30°C

Voltages - graphic card
VIN0            1.250V      1.250V      1.250V

Temperatures - graphic card
TMPIN0          35°C        38°C        36°C
```

I would like to ask another question. In case it is a problem with power supply or battery. Could it damage other parts of the system? I am especially worried about HDD since I am in the middle of some bigger work project and I have a lot of personal "GoPro" videos/photos from my vacation. It would be very unpleaseant for me if I lose those.

Also is it possible to guess what are the chances it would fail to load/damage system? I am currently quite short on my time and money budget and preferably I would like to wait ~2 months if possible. I am in the middle of big project and really don't feel like searching/buying for computer parts and than assembling it and setting everything up in SW part. No to mention that spending 3 times my monthly budget on new PC that would last few years is quite big change in my plans.

---

EDIT 2:
I am going to buy new hardware as I said in the comment but I just wanted to write this in case someone has the same problem. I've checked the battery and the problem persisted. I've also checked those motherboard capacitors and they all looked fine. So like you have said the problem is most likely power supply.

Comment: motherboard details??? power details?

Comment: @Sam - You could replace the CMOS battery to start, its cheap enough, that a replacement won't break the bank.  The other things that could be wrong, honestly, would make you end up spending more to fix the computer then a new computer would cost.

Comment: @Sam : Do you have a graphics card connected?.If yes, try booting without it and check issue is still there or not.

Comment: PSU could be getting tired (capacitors have a lifespan, after which they don't store charge so well), but CMOS battery would be a cheaper first port of call.

Comment: I would also guess the power supply and its capacitors are dying. CMOS battery should not have any effect on this, PC should be able to boot even without it. If the battery is dead, you would lose date/time settings + all BIOS settings (BIOS would display warning about using default values).

Comment: Based on your description, my bet would be on the power supply.  They're also relatively inexpensive and simple to replace.  You could test with the other power supply to see if you get a normal POST beep.  You could also try to boot using a CD/DVD, external drive, or even borrow a SATA drive (you might get errors due to mismatched drivers, but you could test whether things power up and it attempts to boot).  If the PSU is dead, there isn't likely to be damage to other parts.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'll leave it as is for now and next month build new machine. I've selected the answer that could be the most helpful to someone with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, this is one of a few things:

- Check your motherboard details to see if there is a battery for the BIOS CMOS memory. If so, try replacing it.
- Run up a tool such as [HWMONITOR](http://www.cpuid.com/) to see if the motherboard voltages are correct. If not, suspect the power supply. You might do some direct testing if you have the skills and a suitable multimeter to hand.
- Next up is to visually check the motherboard capacitors (cylindrical things) to see if the ends are bulging. If they have a significant bulge, time for a new motherboard.
- After that, do some research to see whether you can get a cheap replacement for the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you can do is change PSU or change MBRD.  Changing PSU is easier. If you change PSU and have the same problem, then, you could try yet another PSU, if still the same problem then say it looks like the motherboard and then either get another motherboard or give up on the motherboard and keep anything worthwhile from the computer.

You cannot troubleshoot if you don't have duplicate parts.. if not MBRD, then everything else. In your case you need other PSUs to test the motherboard with, otherwise you can't really troubleshoot it (unless you get lucky somehow).